# Error while passing a list of strings in multiprocessing pool.starmap

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying some webscraping. I am passing a list containing URLs to pool.starmap , and I am facing arguments error. Showing a simplified version of my code:

Can somebody help me with this?
And sorry if I am doing something silly.

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def func(x):
    print(x)

s = ["cat","foo","bar","you","and","me"] #this list contains ~50 URLs in actual code

with Pool() as pool:
    pool.starmap(func,s)
```

This gives me error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                          
File "g.py", line 8, in <module>                                                                                                            
  pool.starmap(func,s)                                                                                                                    
File "C:\Users\Gunjan\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 274, in starmap                                                          return 
  self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()                                                                    
File "C:\Users\Gunjan\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get                                                              
  raise self._value                                                                                                                       
File "C:\Users\Gunjan\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
  result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))                                                                                                    
File "C:\Users\Gunjan\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
  return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))                                                                                      
TypeError: func() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Comment: post complete working example code to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the regular `map()`

try:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def func(x):
    print(x)

s = ["cat","foo","bar","you","and","me"] #this list contains ~50 URLs in actual code

with Pool() as pool:
    pool.map(func,s)
```

`starmap()` expects each element of the list to be an iterable itself, and it passes the inner iterable's element args to `func`

your elements are strings, which are iterables by character,
so starmap called `func('c', 'a', 't')` for the first element, etc...

here's the definitions + docstrings of both functions:

```py
    def map(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
        '''
        Apply `func` to each element in `iterable`, collecting the results
        in a list that is returned.
        '''
        return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()

    def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
        '''
        Like `map()` method but the elements of the `iterable` are expected to
        be iterables as well and will be unpacked as arguments. Hence
        `func` and (a, b) becomes func(a, b).
        '''
        return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
```

Answer (score 3):

`starmap` expects list of iterables. Check [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap). So use `map` instead.